# Does low battery on Android interfere with Firebase ChildEventListener?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase Realtime Database and ChildEventListener (which subsequently writes to a local Room database). A user of mine reported that they saw a previous node's value show up, and then only after they restarted the activity, the correct / current value showed up. I am trying to reproduce this, but my only suspicion based on the photo they sent to me was that their device's battery level was in the red.

Has anyone ever encountered anything like this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I successfully reproduced it. It appears ChildEventListener does not fire if the 1) device goes into deep idle and 2) battery optimization is enabled for my app. I was able to force it into deep idle, change a value in Firebase and when I tap the power button (which resumes my activity), it can take several seconds for the listener to fire. In one instance, the listener stopped working entirely and required restarting the app.

Answer (score 1):

No low battery does not affect how or what data is retrieved from the Firebase database. The database does not interact with the device functionality.

Comment: Thank you. I'm wondering then if perhaps it has something to do with Android lifecycle - I have the ChildEventListener snippet in the onResume() of my activity. Perhaps this is causing some delay.

Comment: U can use `onStart()`

Comment: Thanks, hmm then I'm not sure. Does childeventlistener still fire onPause() / onStop() or if app is minimized?

Comment: If u use onStart u need to remove the listener in onstop, if you use onResume then remove the listener in on pause, but yes u have to remove it